# Debug electron-app. Is it possible to see js-calls through minidump?

Tags: javascript, debugging, electron, stack-trace

I've faced with crashes that hard-to-reproduce in my electron app. So i've configured the crash-reporter and got minidump. Using the breakpad tools i've transfrom minidump to stack-trace, and got a lot of info about chromium/electron calls when crash happened, but this stack trace has no info about any JS calls. So my question is it possible to somehow add js stack-trace to the electron minidump file?

Comment: im intrested to know as well, have you found a solution?